# Reading data from an array with json

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode

In a php script I have the following

```
$jsonurlpers = "https://api.openarch.nl/1.1/records/show.json?archive=nha&identifier=8554bfba-9fd9-4ca2-876c-feb7da095d6c";
$jsondatapers = file_get_contents($jsonurlpers);
```

That string I want to decode with the next command

```
$jsonpers = json_decode($jsondatapers ,true)[0];
```

But somewhere it did not work...

When I go to to the `@jsonulpers` I see :

```
Event   
 EventType  "Overlijden"
 EventDate  
  Year  "1901"
  Month "7"
  Day   "7"
EventPlace  
  Place "Egmond-Binnen"
RelationEP
```

Can some one tell me how I can read the value behind `EventType` in a variable? I tried different options but none works...

Thanks,
Fred

I did try this

e.g.

```
  $itemevent = $jsonpers['Event'];
  $itemeventtype = $itemevent['EventType']);
```

abs I thought

`$itemeventtype` would have a value of "`Overlijden`", but it was empty

Comment: Do: `$jsonpers = json_decode($jsondatapers ,true); var_dump($jsonpers);`.    And this will get you "Egmond-Binnen": `print($jsonpers["Person"][0]["BirthPlace"]["Place"]);`

Comment: Thanks, and to search through all the persons i need a loop...  i think.

Comment: Can i also ask what the sequence number is?  So i have the same person and the correct relationEP?

Comment: I added an answer, with the contents of the JSON-answer message. I do hope my explanation is clear .

Answer (score 0):

The (json-)output from the url you gave looks like this:

```
{
   "Event" : {
      "EventType" : "Overlijden",
      "EventDate" : {
         "Month" : "7",
         "Day" : "7",
         "Year" : "1901"
      },
      "EventPlace" : {
         "Place" : "Egmond-Binnen"
      }
   },
   "RelationEP" : [
      {
         "RelationType" : "Overledene",
         "EventKeyRef" : "Event1",
         "PersonKeyRef" : "Person1"
      },
      {
         "PersonKeyRef" : "Person2",
         "RelationType" : "Vader",
         "EventKeyRef" : "Event1"
      },
      {
         "PersonKeyRef" : "Person3",
         "RelationType" : "Moeder",
         "EventKeyRef" : "Event1"
      }
   ],
   "Source" : {
      "SourcePlace" : {
         "Place" : "Egmond-Binnen / Egmond-Binnen"
      },
      "SourceAvailableScans" : {
         "Scan" : {
            "Uri" : "https://nha.blob.core.windows.net/scans/BS%20Overlijden/Egmond-Binnen/1901/RNH_O_EGB_1901_006-a.jpg",
            "OrderSequenceNumber" : "1"
         }
      },
      "SourceLastChangeDate" : "2015-07-31",
      "SourceRemark" : {
         "Value" : "Datadump ExportBS+Overlijden_20210302_102010.csv van NHA via e-mail"
      },
      "SourceReference" : {
         "InstitutionName" : "Noord-Hollands Archief",
         "DocumentNumber" : "14",
         "Place" : "Haarlem"
      },
      "RecordGUID" : "{8554bfba-9fd9-4ca2-876c-feb7da095d6c}",
      "SourceIndexDate" : {
         "To" : "1901-12-31",
         "From" : "1901-01-01"
      },
      "SourceDate" : {
         "Year" : "1901",
         "Month" : "7",
         "Day" : "8"
      },
      "SourceType" : "BS Overlijden"
   },
   "Person" : [
      {
         "BirthPlace" : {
            "Place" : "Egmond-Binnen"
         },
         "PersonName" : {
            "PersonNameLastName" : "Baltus",
            "PersonNameFirstName" : "Aafje"
         },
         "Gender" : "Vrouw",
         "Age" : {
            "PersonAgeYears" : "8 maanden"
         }
      },
      {
         "PersonName" : {
            "PersonNameFirstName" : "Jan",
            "PersonNameLastName" : "Baltus"
         }
      },
      {
         "PersonName" : {
            "PersonNameLastName" : "Kuijper",
            "PersonNameFirstName" : "Grietje"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

After `"Person":`, you see a `[`, which means there is an array of Persons.

The first person does have a "BirthPlace", for the other persons it seems to be unknown what the "BirthPlace" is, because it is not mentioned in the json.

`print($jsonpers["Person"][0]["PersonName"]["PersonFirstName"]` should be: "Aafje"

and

`print($jsonpers["Person"][2]["PersonName"]["PersonFirstName"]` should be: "Grietje"